# свойство enabled пункта контекстного меню для разных gridview

Tags: c#, winforms

В форме есть grdControl1 и gridview1 и gridview2. Имеется контекстное меню с пунктом "Подробно". Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии контекстного меню на gridview1 пункт "Подробно" был disable, а при нажатии на gridView2 - enable. В свойствах по умолчанию ставлю Enabled = false, а потом в методе загрузки гридов пишу

```
 if (gridControl1.FocusedView == gridView2)
        {
            подробноToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Но это не срабатывает, все равно пункт "Подробно" остается disable и на gridview1(правильно) и на gridview2(неправильно) В чем может быть причина? Можно ли так сделать вообще?

Answer (score 0):

> а потом в методе загрузки гридов пишу ...

Судя по всему в методе загрузки ни одно отображение (view) не обладает фокусом. Соответственно, условие не выполняется и пункт меню остается отключенным. В любом случае код загрузки выполняется только раз и не обновляет состояние меню при каждом вызове.

Чтобы включать/отключать доступность пункта меню во время исполнения нужно обрабатывать событие [`ContextMenuStrip.Opening`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void myContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //доступен если только сфокусирован gridView2
        подробноToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = (gridControl1.FocusedView == gridView2);
    }
```

Можно было бы также воспользоваться свойством [`ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), но, полагаю, там в обоих случаях будет `GridControl`.

Вообще, компоненты DevExpress (насколько я понял, речь о них) предоставляют свои контекстные меню и свои способы их кастомизации. Посмотрите статью «[Creating Custom Context Menus](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1292/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Popup-Menus/Creating-Custom-Context-Menus)»